Access downloaded secure files through variables
I have a template for my Azure DevOps pipeline, which downloads multiple secure files. In the same template (and same job), another task that executes a bash script should access each secure file download one by one and access the secure file to do an operation.
However, here I run into trouble. Say I have downloaded a secure file through task named 'downloadTask'. If I then access the secureFilePath through $(downloadTask.secureFilPath), this works great.
However, in my case the task names are referenced in the for loop, like so:
for taskName in $taskNames; do
    echo $(${taskName}.secureFilePath)

When I try to run this command, I get the following error: downloadTask.secureFilePath: command not found. I'm confused about the issue that's causing this error, and am not getting much wiser.
Which adjustments should I make to resolve this issue?
Edit - add pipeline code:
parameters:
  - name: credentials
    type: string
  - name: secureFileNames
    type: object
    default: []

steps:
  - ${{ each secureFileName in parameters.secureFileNames }}:
    - task: DownloadSecureFile@1
      displayName: 'Download secure file: ${{ secureFileName }}'
      name: ${{ replace(secureFileName, '.', '_') }}
      inputs:
        secureFile: '${{ secureFileName }}'

  - task: AWSShellScript@1
    displayName: 'someDisplayName'
    inputs:
      awsCredentials: ${{ parameters.credentials }}
      regionName: $(DEFAULT_REGION)
      scriptType: 'inline'
      inlineScript: |
        secureFileNames="${{ join(' ', parameters.secureFileNames) }}"
        sanitizedTaskNames=${secureFileNames//./_}
 
        for taskName in $sanitizedTaskNames; do
          echo "$(${taskName}.secureFileName)"
        done
        


Could you please share your pipeline code or at least the most relevant parts?

Use https://www.shellcheck.net/ and make the changes suggested.
$(...) runs its contents in a subshell and returns the stdout.  $(${taskName}.secureFilePath) is trying to execute it's content, but the value of ${taskName} is downloadTask, and downloadTask.secureFilePath is apparently not something it can find in the $PATH as executable.
what were you trying to accomplish?

@RuiJarimba Added a modified version of the template I'm using

echo "$(${taskName}.secureFileName)" won't work - variables with macro syntax $(var) get processed before a task executes during runtime. See Understand variable syntax

If you're processing each secure file separately, consider running the AWSShellScript@1 script as part of the ${{ each secureFileName ... }} loop. Or maybe add an intermediate task that copies each secure file to a new and empty folder, and then iterate over the files in that folder in the AWSShellScript@1 task?

@RuiJarimba with regards to the syntax, what confuses me is that the error message is displaying the correct variable (downloadTask.secureFilePath: command not found) which shows that it resolved the ${taskName}.
In the end I need to concatinate all files, which is why I thought this approach would be quick and easy. Apparently not :-)

@DominiqueM if I'm not mistaken, Azure DevOps will try to expand the expression $(${taskName}.secureFileName)  BEFORE running the script

The task name should be the name property of each DownloadSecureFile@1 task, which is ${{ replace(secureFileName, '.', '_') }}. Since the names of the tasks are iterated with ${{each secureFileName}}, the AWSShellScript@1 task should be under the same - ${{ each}} expression with DownloadSecureFile@1 task.

Assuming the following secure files:

I was able to create a pipeline that lists the files dynamically.
Code is not pretty, but it works.
parameters:
  - name: secureFiles
    type: object
    default:
      - name: foo
        secureFileName: foo.txt
      - name: bar
        secureFileName: bar.txt

trigger: none

pool: 
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

steps:
  - checkout: none

  - ${{ each secureFile in parameters.secureFiles }}:
    - task: DownloadSecureFile@1
      displayName: 'Download secure file: ${{ secureFile.name }}'
      name: ${{ secureFile.name }}
      inputs:
        secureFile: '${{ secureFile.secureFileName }}'

    - script: |
        cat "$(${{ secureFile.name }}.secureFilePath)"
      displayName: 'Display secure file content: ${{ secureFile.name }}'

    # This works too - secure files are download to $(Agent.TempDirectory) by default
    - script: |
        cat "$(Agent.TempDirectory)/${{ secureFile.secureFileName }}"
      displayName: 'Display secure file content: ${{ secureFile.name }}'

  - script: |
      files="${{ join(' ', parameters.secureFiles.*.secureFileName) }}"

      for file in $files; do
        echo "Path of secure file $file: $(Agent.TempDirectory)/$file"
      done
    displayName: 'Display all secure files path'

Notes:

I'm using an object as opposed to a simple array with the names and paths of the secure files, which makes it easier to use them in the tasks without the need to sanitize the paths:

  - name: secureFiles
    type: object
    default:
      - name: foo
        secureFileName: foo.txt
      - name: bar
        secureFileName: bar.txt


Secure files are downloaded by default to $(Agent.TempDirectory), so we can take advantage of that to simplify the script

Pipeline logs of the DownloadSecureFile@1 task:
##[debug]secureFile=3f70c6b3-0575-4ab7-ae27-89a1c58d5fef
...
##[debug]secure file name for id 3f70c6b3-0575-4ab7-ae27-89a1c58d5fef = foo.txt
##[debug]Agent.TempDirectory=/home/vsts/work/_temp
##[debug]Absolute path for pathSegments: /home/vsts/work/_temp,foo.txt = /home/vsts/work/_temp/foo.txt
##[debug]Downloading secure file contents to: /home/vsts/work/_temp/foo.txt
##[debug]secure file ticket for id 3f70c6b3-0575-4ab7-ae27-89a1c58d5fef = ***
...
##[debug]Downloaded secure file contents to: /home/vsts/work/_temp/foo.txt
##[debug]set secureFilePath=/home/vsts/work/_temp/foo.txt
##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.setvariable variable=secureFilePath;isOutput=false;issecret=false;]/home/vsts/work/_temp/foo.txt


Clear demo, much appreciated!
Using the defaullt directory ($(Agent.TempDirectory)) to which secure files are downloaded solves the issue for me, as I am no longer dependent on getting the secure file path through .secureFilePath.
